# how to root galaxy ace gt 5830 gingerbread 2.3.6

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I already install Clockwork-Mod Recovery (CWM) v5 and i used that upd_1.zip for root my galaxy ace but it didn't,  any one knows how do that thing.

Comment: [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com) is more detail about device setting.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free. Free to ask questions, thank you for every one

Comment: Yes, and the community which runs it is free to decide what's on topic and what's not, in accordance with the site FAQs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did a quick google search and think this can help you:
http://androidadvices.com/root-samsung-galaxy-ace-gt-s5830-gingerbread-firmware/

I Recomend reading the whole but if you want to skip to the rooting just jump to part 3: http://androidadvices.com/root-samsung-galaxy-ace-gt-s5830-gingerbread-firmware/3/.

Many roms have root set in rom properties this will also root your device, which meens that the rom will actually root for you.